# Can a Girl Avatar learn northern waterbending?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In ATLA it is seen that master Pakku said that we don't teach girls waterbending. So is it different for avatar girls or they can't learn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t believe there is a canon answer to this, seeing as the rule was abolished before Korra’s birth.

What we do know is that the Avatar always masters the elements. There are several possibilities as to how this happens with water bending:

- There are water bending masters that live elsewhere that could teach the Avatar. Kyoshi mastered the elements under the instructions of a gang of [criminals from the Earth Kingdom](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Kirima). The Southern Tribe, though never as grand as the North, was in a lot better shape before Sozin’s war started and was doubtlessly the place where many other Avatars were trained.
- It’s not clear how far the rule dates back. It may not have been in place even hundreds of years ago, when Yangchen, the Air Nomad Avatar before Aang, lived.
- The Avatar may be an exception to the rule, for one reason or another. For one, the Avatar mastering all the elements is important to the balance of the world. It’s even considered an honor to train the Avatar.  Also, the Avatar almost certainly was trained in the north hundreds of times, as both man and woman, before there was a unified tribe there with rules, so why would they not be able to again?